# Android non-full screen app startup during voice call

Tags: android, call, startup, voice, android-2.2-froyo

Is it possible to start the application on the Android phone (starting with Froyo), when there is an incoming voice call? In other words, the incoming voice call should trigger the application startup.

In such a case the application should not be full-screen, but should cover only part of the screen to not hide the native controls for accepting or rejecting the call.

If it is not supported now - is anybody aware about some plans to support such a feature in future releases?

Comment: No comment at all??Thanks, STeN